# CSS limit depth styles can be applied to elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Does anybody know of a solution to limit the child depth when selecting an element with `CSS`?

Example:

```
.my-class div div:end(styles:here)
```

This would prevent having to add `CSS` classes to every single second div in the page while preventing styles from being passed on down to the third fourth etc. child.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specifically tell it to search only 1 level deeper with [**the `>` operator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators).

Consider the following example:

```
#target > p > span {
    background: red;
}
```

This will search `#target` for a **direct** child element `<p>`, and within that element, will search for a **direct** child element `<span>`. So if there is a nested `<p>` element, and a span inside of it, it won't be affected.

A very common use is for nested list items, where you want the main list to style, but the secondary list to not.

```
ul#parent > li /* Direct descendant. */
ul#parent > li > ul > li /* 2 levels deep descendant. */
```

Comment: Apparently you can't use this to style text nodes directly under the body tag, even though those get included along with all other unstyled nodes if you just style the body.  For instance, you can't give top-level text a blue color by itself this way, if you style the body with color:blue all unstyled text at all depths turns blue.

Comment: @Michael that is, partially, because, by specs, the body cannot hold text nodes. The body can only hold block level elements.

Comment: But I see all the time something like this: <body>Some text. <other tags> </body>.

Comment: @Michael: And I see people not stopping at a stop sign all the time. It doesn't make it right. Also, the browser will probably interpret that in a way you don't expect.

Comment: And strictly speaking the spec appears to allow it: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/body.html#body.  Body can contain flow content, which is defined as "flow elements intermixed with normal character data".

Comment: @Michael: Indeed, then it was changed since the last time I visited it. TIL.

Comment: I think I see why my approach won't work though... using '>' the style is only applied to the child node but since all children of *that* node are contained in it, it applies to them too.  There is no selector for plain text, so it has to apply to the entire document (unless explicitly changed).